# Grouping in Linq ( on multiple fields)

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am grouping some data using linq as following :

```
var groupedData = from row in salesTable.AsEnumerable()                   
group row by   
row.Field<string>("InvoiceNum") into grp
select grp;
```

I want to regroup **groupedData** using some fields like **row.Field("InvoiceNum") , row.Field("InvoiceLineNum")** , I dont know how does the linq grouping works with multiple fields ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an anonymously typed object for the grouping.

```
 var groupedData = from row in salesTable.AsEnumerable()                   
                   group row by new
                   {
                        InvoiceNum = row.Field<string>("InvoiceNum"),
                        InvoiceLineNum = row.Field<string>("InvoiceLineNum")
                   }
                   into grp
                   select grp;
```

or using a named class

```
public class InvoiceGrouping : IEquatable<InvoiceGrouping>
{
     public string InvoiceNum { get; set; }
     public string InvoiceLineNum { get; set; }

     public bool Equals( InvoiceGrouping other )
     {
         return other != null 
                && this.InvoiceNum == other.InvoiceNum
                && this.InvoiceLineNum == other.InvoiceLineNum;
     }

     public override bool Equals( object other )
     {
         return Equals( other as InvoiceGrouping );
     }

     public override int GetHashCode()
     {
         unchecked
         {
            int hash = 17;
            hash *= (this.InvoiceNum != null ? 23 + this.InvoiceNum.GetHashCode() : 1);
            hash *= (this.InvoiceLineNum != null ? 23 + this.InvoiceLineNum.GetHashCode() : 1 );
            return hash;
         }
     }
 }

 var groupedData = from row in salesTable.AsEnumerable()                   
                   group row by new InvoiceGrouping
                   {
                        InvoiceNum = row.Field<string>("InvoiceNum"),
                        InvoiceLineNum = row.Field<string>("InvoiceLineNum")
                   }
                   into grp
                   select grp;
```

Comment: It probably doesn't have to be anonymous, strictly, but this is certainly the classic approach

Comment: @Marc - right, he could create an instance of a named class as well if that makes more sense in context.

Comment: Can you give an example of what do you mean by named class instance??

Comment: @Huzaifa - sure, it's just a matter of creating a class (or using an existing one) that has the properties you need and then using it's constructor (or the short-hand object initializer syntax, which I would prefer) to create one of these instead of an anonymous object.  I've updated with an example.

Comment: @Huzaifa We just mean `new SomeType {Foo=blah, Bar=blop}` - but honestly, ignore my point; an anonymous type (as shown in this answer) is perfect for this. I was being pedantic, and probably added confusion in the process; my bad.

Comment: Using a tuple is another option, though to access the values of the key would be slightly awkward but is easier than creating a new class just for the sake of grouping (which by the way should implement `IEquatable<T>` to be useful here).

Comment: @Jeff - and that's why using the anonymous object is to be preferred.  Grrr.  Updated with suitable additions and overrides.